# XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: ajax, web-services

I am getting error as

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://abc.com/xml. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

in chrmoe while connecting to web serives. I tried to use  in header section of html. But its not working. Web services I am calling is not support JSONP. Same code is working fine with IE8. Could any one please help

Comment: What URL exactly are you trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling URL in other domain than the original page then browser forbids such request by default. In order to make XMLHttpRequest to URL with different domain you have to place in the root folder of the remote server clientaccesspolicy.xml file for cross-domain acces. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx